# time calculation between two date time based on shop opening and closing time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

me has a table in oracle which TEMPhas shop open & Close time.

```
| COMPANY_ID | DAY_OF_WEEK | SHOP OPEN TIME | SHOP CLOSE TIME |

|------------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|

| shop 1 | 1 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 2 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 3 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 4 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 5 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 6 | +00 10:00:00.000000 | +00 21:30:00.000000 |

| shop 1 | 7 | +00 11:00:00.000000 | +00 18:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 1 | +00 10:30:00.000000 | +00 20:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 2 | +00 09:30:00.000000 | +00 22:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 3 | +00 09:30:00.000000 | +00 22:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 4 | +00 09:30:00.000000 | +00 22:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 5 | +00 11:00:00.000000 | +00 18:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 6 | +00 09:30:00.000000 | +00 22:00:00.000000 |

| shop 2 | 7 | +00 09:00:00.000000 | +00 22:00:00.000000 |
```

Day-1 is saturday

me has another table for complaint, when customer complain TEMPthan we resolve teh query and calculate how much time we took to resolve. We don't take time in teh consideration if teh shop is close at that time. So if shop is open on Monday 09:00 to 22:00 TEMPthan night 22:00 to morning 09:00 time won't be considered .

complain table:

```
| SHOP | COMPLAIN NUMBER | COMPLAIN DAY TIME | RESOLVE DAY TIME | TIME TAKEN TO RESOLVE in minutes |

|-------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------------------------------|

| SHOP1 | 1 | 01/10/2022 08:20 | 01/10/2022 16:10 | 310 |

| SHOP1 | 2 | 01/10/2022 08:20 | 06/10/2022 09:50 |
```

me have calculated manually for complaint number 1, time taken to resolve teh query is 310 mins.
01/10/2022 was Saturday and shop opening time was 11:00 AM based on shop open and close time time taken to resolve teh complaint is 5 hours 10 mins which 310 mins,
if dis day would be Monday and as we see opening time on Monday is 10AM TEMPthan time taken to resolve would be 370 mins. (open and closing time can be different for different shop for different day)

In dis example complaint and problem is for same day, so dis is bit easier but

If teh complaint stays for 4 or 5 days. How we should calculate as every day shop opening and closing time are different. So in teh second case time taken should be 4550 mins

01/10-570 complaint open for all day as complaint logged before shop opened ()

02/10-750 complaint open for all day

03/10-750 complaint open for all day

04/10-750 complaint open for all day

05/10-420 complaint open for all day

06/10-740 complaint close 10 mins before shop closing

Total is 3980 mins, Please halp
This question is currently in our queue. You'll get an email notification when we've added an answer

Comment: Shop 1 is only open until 21:30., so did you mean to show complaint 2 resolved at 21:20 rather than 22:20 since you said 10 minutes before closing? I make the total for at one 3860 though - I think you've added an extra full day (690 minutes)?

Answer (score 0):

To get the overlaps with the shop opening times, you could use a hierarchical query or recursive CTE to split each complaint into its separate days, and calculate the equivalent day number (which seems to be 1 for Sunday through to 6 for Saturday), something like:

```
with rcte (shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day, active_day_of_week) as (
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    trunc(complain_day_time), trunc(complain_day_time + 1) - trunc(complain_day_time + 1, 'IW') + 1
  from complaints
  union all
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day + 1, trunc(active_day + 2) - trunc(active_day + 2, 'IW') + 1
  from rcte
  where active_day < trunc(resolve_day_time)
)
select * from rcte
order by shop, complain_number, active_day
```

| SHOP | COMPLAIN_NUMBER | COMPLAIN_DAY_TIME | RESOLVE_DAY_TIME | ACTIVE_DAY | ACTIVE_DAY_OF_WEEK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 1 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-01 16:10:00 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 7 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 7 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 2 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-04 00:00:00 | 3 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-05 00:00:00 | 4 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 2022-10-06 00:00:00 | 5 |

Then join each of those days to the shop times on that day, and use least/greatest to figure out how much of that day's hours to include, subtracting the active end/start times and multiplying the resulting number of days by 1440 to get it in minutes; and then sum up all of those for each complaint:

```
with rcte (shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day, active_day_of_week) as (
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    trunc(complain_day_time), trunc(complain_day_time + 1) - trunc(complain_day_time + 1, 'IW') + 1
  from complaints
  union all
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day + 1, trunc(active_day + 2) - trunc(active_day + 2, 'IW') + 1
  from rcte
  where active_day < trunc(resolve_day_time)
)
select c.shop, c.complain_number, c.complain_day_time, c.resolve_day_time,
  sum(round(1440 * (least(c.active_day + s.shop_close_time, c.resolve_day_time)
   - greatest(c.active_day + s.shop_open_time, c.complain_day_time)))) as active_mins
from rcte c
join shops s on s.company_id = c.shop
and s.day_of_week = c.active_day_of_week
group by c.shop, c.complain_number, c.complain_day_time, c.resolve_day_time
order by c.shop, c.complain_number
```

| SHOP | COMPLAIN_NUMBER | COMPLAIN_DAY_TIME | RESOLVE_DAY_TIME | ACTIVE_MINS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 1 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-01 16:10:00 | 310 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 3860 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wz0njIe2?hide=56) showing the intermediate calculation as well.

I've adjusted the second complaint's resolve time to 21:20 because that shop is only open until 21:30 and you said "complaint close 10 mins before shop closing". That gets a total of 3860 minutes for that complaint - you seem to have added an extra day to your calculation to get 4550.

---

> However in some scenario calls also get close before shop open. ... We just need to count the time when shop is open. Call can be open and close out of hour also.

This can probably be streamlined a bit, but if you get the active start/end for each day you can use a case expression to decide if that is after/before the shop hours and ignore it if not:

```
with rcte (shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day, active_day_of_week) as
(
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    trunc(complain_day_time), trunc(complain_day_time + 1) - trunc(complain_day_time + 1, 'IW') + 1
  from complaints
  union all
  select shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
    active_day + 1, trunc(active_day + 2) - trunc(active_day + 2, 'IW') + 1
  from rcte
  where active_day < trunc(resolve_day_time)
),
cte (shop, complain_number, complain_day_time, resolve_day_time,
  active_start, active_end) as
(
  select r.shop, r.complain_number, r.complain_day_time, r.resolve_day_time,
    greatest(r.active_day + s.shop_open_time, r.complain_day_time) as active_start,
    least(r.active_day + s.shop_close_time, r.resolve_day_time) as active_end
  from rcte r
  join shops s on s.company_id = r.shop
  and s.day_of_week = r.active_day_of_week
)
select c.shop, c.complain_number, c.complain_day_time, c.resolve_day_time,
  sum(nvl(round(1440 * (
    case when c.active_end >= c.complain_day_time then c.active_end end
      - case when c.active_start <= c.resolve_day_time then c.active_start end
  )), 0)) as active_mins
from cte c
group by c.shop, c.complain_number, c.complain_day_time, c.resolve_day_time
order by c.shop, c.complain_number
```

| SHOP | COMPLAIN_NUMBER | COMPLAIN_DAY_TIME | RESOLVE_DAY_TIME | ACTIVE_MINS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop 1 | 1 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-01 16:10:00 | 310 |
| shop 1 | 2 | 2022-10-01 08:20:00 | 2022-10-06 21:20:00 | 3860 |
| shop 2 | 3 | 2022-10-05 21:45:00 | 2022-10-06 10:50:00 | 15 |
| shop 2 | 4 | 2022-10-05 22:10:00 | 2022-10-06 11:15:00 | 15 |
| shop 2 | 5 | 2022-10-05 22:10:00 | 2022-10-06 10:50:00 | 0 |
| shop 2 | 6 | 2022-10-05 17:53:00 | 2022-10-06 11:16:00 | 263 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/66542z2-) with a complaint that opens in-hours and closes out-of hours, one that opens out-of-hours and close in-hours, and one that both opens and closes out of hours - giving zero active minutes. I've also left in the original code for comparison so you can see those three get different (wrong, based on your comment) results.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for this solutions, though I am stuggling one place. Normal scenario a call should close only when shop is open. However in some scenario calls also get close before shop open. With this query that values comes in minus, so in our final query this minus value added with active_mins and it show less active min. i.e.  shop-2 on 5th day shop open at 11:00 AM however if the call close at 10:50 that day then Total active min -10 minutes(10:50-11:00) as shop opened at 11 only. We just need to count the time when shop is open. Call can be open and close out of hour also. Plz help.

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan - so if a complaint is made just after a shop closes and is resolved before it reopens the following day, the active time is zero?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: OK, that's what the updated answer does. Hope that works for you now.

Comment: Something off, one of the shop comp_open_time-05-FEB-23 16.53.00 and complain_close_time-06-FEB-23 08.46.00 .shop open/close time-day_of_week-1: 09:00/21:00 and shop open/close time-day_of_week-2: 08:30/22:00. So the first day it was open for 247 minutes, this query gives me 240 minutes.second day it is fine. Let me know whats needs to be amend.

Comment: What needs to be amended is my typing... I'd somehow used 1400 instead of 1440 in the new calculation. Which wasn't obvious on the short durations I was focused on, but threw off the others. Fixed, and I've included one with 247 minutes on the first day so you can see that's now right.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you and you are a superstar. I dont understand how exactly this is working but I will read once I am done with this work. Really appreciate your help and let you know if I stuck in this. As of now this seems fab.